# I would like to send am "http 200" using curl

Tags: php, http, curl

Im doing responses to Paypal IPN system

I want to send an

> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

before i send a `php curl` with data

I think i should do this in `php curl` too (rather than a `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` )

can anyone supply me with code? or is the header ok?

Comment: [HTTP 200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) is a _response_ status code. What makes you think you should (or can) send it when sending a request?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

lol

Answer (score -2):

```
 function curl()
    {
      $ch = curl_init();

      $data = array(
      "Content-type: ,
      "POST /your api curl method HTTP/1.1",
      "Accept: ",
      "Host: "host url",
      "Content-length: your param length
       );

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, post url here);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post param here );
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

       $output = curl_exec($ch);

       $err = curl_error($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       return $output;
    }
```

should send it in header

Comment: Why would sending a POST _request_ cause a _response_ header to be included? Also, you are missing a quote. Please take care to provide accurate answers and to explain them.